Regular Expression to Prohibit Certain Zero Values and Leading Zeros
I need a regular expression that accomplishes the following:
Prohibits input values like:
012
0.00
0
0.0
0.000

Allows input values like:
1
0.01
1.12
10
10.5

Here's the regular expression I am currently working with:
regex
^(?!0\d)(?!0(.0{1,2})?$)\d+(.\d{1,2})?$

Could you please provide detailed information on what this regular expression does, and suggest any modifications if necessary to meet the requirements?
I would appreciate any help or clarification on how this expression works and how to adjust it for my needs.
Thank you!

Use a negative lookahead that matches 0 at the beginning.

What about 0.125?

If you copy your regex expression to https://regex101.com/ you will see full explanation on the right.

"What about 0.125?" - 0.125 should also be disallowed

Please do not only give examples, but also some rules you want to have checked. From your examples I would guess the following rules: maximum 3 decimal digits, maximum 1 dot for the comma. An input must not start with 0 except if that is immediately followed by a dot. An input has to be finished with a non-zero digit if a dot is contained. --- Are my assumptions correct? Did I miss a rule?

@user27358886 Why? What language are you using. Just use that. I just spent 10 minutes, it would take me 5 to learn how to do it in the language of your choice. This looks like a parse a number that's not 0.

@cyberbrain
I want a regular expression that:
Prohibits:
Numbers starting with a leading zero (e.g., 01, 0234)
Isolated zero (0) and zero with an invalid decimal part (e.g., 0.0, 0.00, 0.000)
Allows:
Whole numbers (e.g., 10, 99)
Decimal numbers with one or two digits after the point (e.g., 0.01, 1.12, 90.00)

This is utterly trivial if you don’t use a regular expression.

@PeteBecker
But I specifically need a regular expression

Yes, using regular expressions it becomes a mess, because the only way to do it without negation (which is a can of worms of it's own and isn't even supported by many regular expression runtimes) is by using a bunch of ors. I'm not a regex god, but give me another 2 hours and i'll get this done. I don't think it's worth it. If this is for educational purposes, please provide a complete list of all possible examples, and your notes per part. Here's my last attempt: ^((([1-9]\d+)(\.(\d|\d+[1-9]))?)|(\d(\.([1-9]|\d+[1-9]))))|(([1-9]\d+)|([1-9]))$

As in. If you want me to keep working, first expand my work into an answer.

@JulianAAvarC
Prohibits input values like:
01
001
0001
0234
0.00
0
0.0
0.000
Allows input values like:
1.00
1.11
90.00
99.99
0.10
0.01
1.12
10
1
5
55
10.5

Yes. I wasn't done. But your tried in the past to work with negation in your regex. Go play with a bunch of ors, and come back if you still cant get it.

@user27358886 please amend your question to include your extra test cases from your comment.

Please [edit] the question and explain why the first examples should be rejected and the latter examples should be excepted.  State the rules.  Don't make us guess.

You have a problem you did not provide context on, but you tell us the solution has to be a regex. That's what we call an XY problem - asking about solution Y when the problem is X and could be solved trivially without Y. I would need more details to produce a good regex, but I'd rather help with the actual problem than spend energy based on assumptions.

It's always best to provide a precise description of your problem in words, reserving examples for illustration. For example, my understanding of your question is that you wish to confirm that a given string is the representation of a positive integer with no leading zeroes or a float whose integer part is zero or is the representation of a positive integer with no leading zeroes and whose fractional part is comprised of one or more digits, the right-most one being a digit other than zero. While I may have misunderstood the question that is the type of unambiguous statement that is needed...

...Once you have stated the problem precisely writing the needed regular expression if often straightforward.

Your lookahead-regex a bit improved: ^(?!0\.0+$|0\d*$)\d+(?:\.\d\d?)?$

I would go with this regular expression:
^(?:[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d\d?)?|0\.(?:[1-9]\d?|0[1-9]))$

It combines various cases:

[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d\d?)?
This case is for numbers >= 1. They have to start with a non-zero digit ([1-9]), can be followed by 0 or more digits (including 0, \d*), and optionally be followed by a literal dot with one or two digits ((?:\.\d\d?)?)
0\.(?:[1-9]\d?|\d[1-9])
This case covers numbers between 0 and 1: They start with a 0 followed by a decimal point (0\.), followed by two sub-cases enclosed in an non-capturing group (?: )

[1-9]\d?
The number after the comma does not start with zero - but has only one or two digits.
0[1-9]
The number after the comma does start with zero, but has to have a second digit that is not zero.



All that options are combined with the "or" operator | and the whole expression is enclosed with "start of input" ^ and "end of input" $ to be sure that you do not only match a part of the whole input but e.g. a zero sneaks in before the expression that is just not matched.
A more technical and detailed explanation can be found at regex101, there you can also try several inputs and play around with the expression itself.

I believe your regex needs a small tweak as it matches '1.50' (and '1.500', etc). While it's not clear whether a string containing a period can end with a zero, it appears from a comment you made on the question that you assume that to be one of the requirements.

About the two branches of your alternation: the first doesn't end with $ and the second doesn't start with ^. In other words, you can write ^branch1$|^branch2$ or ^(?:branch1|branch2)$ but not ^branch1|branch2$. Note also that if the pattern is used as a pattern html attribute, or with a "full match" method , it doesn't matter since anchors are implicit in these cases.

@CasimiretHippolyte thanks for your heads up, I updated the regex (and the link to regex101) to use the start and end of input markers correctly.

@CarySwoveland the original question does not say this clear, but the OP added examples in the comments that make clear that an input "0.10" is valid and should match. I agree that the question could have been asked more concise, but thats (developers) life I would say, to deal with that kind of requirements ;-)

You may wish to attempt to match the following regular expression, which I have written in extended (aka free-spacing) mode (which disregards whitespace and comments) to make it self-documenting.
^             # match start of string
(?:           # begin non-capture group
  # match a positive integer
  [1-9]       # match a digit other than zero
  \d*         # match zero or more digits
|             # or
  # match a positive float that does not end with a zero
  (?:         # begin non-capture group
    0         # match a zero
  |           # or
    # match an integer whose first digit is not zero
    [1-9]     # match a digit other than zero
    \d*       # match zero or more digits
  )           # end non-capture group
  \.          # match a period
  \d*         # match zero or more digits
  [1-9]       # match a digit other than zero
)             # end non-capture group
$             # match end of string

Note that this does not require look-around elements so it should work with most regex engines.
Demo

It may be helpful to first construct an outline of the needed expression.
^             # match start of string
# match a positive integer or a positive float
(?:           # begin outer non-capture group
   # match a positive integer
   ...
|             # or
  # match a positive float
  (?:         # begin inner non-capture group
     0        # match a zero
  |           # or
    # match an integer whose first digit is not zero
    ...
  )           # end inner non-capture group
  \.          # match a period
  # match zero or more digits
    ...      
  # match a digit other than zero
    ...
)             # end outer non-capture group
$             # match end of string


If the comments and whitespaces are removed, and extended mode is not specified, the regular expression becomes
^(?:[1-9]\d*|(?:0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d*[1-9])$



If a number is a properly formatted float, it's (an optional sequence of digits not starting with zero), then any digit (maybe zero), then point, then optional digits, then a non-zero digit.
If a number is an integer, it's a sequence of digits not starting with zero.

As there is probably no elegant way to partially merge those two variants, let's simply combine them into:
^[1-9]\d*$|^(?:[1-9]\d*)?\d\.\d*[1-9]$

Checking with your examples (in Python):
>>> rx = re.compile("^[1-9]\d*$|^(?:[1-9]\d*)?\d\.\d*[1-9]$")
>>> 
>>> rx.match("012")
>>> rx.match("0.00")
>>> rx.match("0")
>>> rx.match("0.0")
>>> rx.match("0.000")
>>> 
>>> rx.match("1")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='1'>
>>> rx.match("0.01")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='0.01'>
>>> rx.match("1.12")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='1.12'>
>>> rx.match("10")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='10'>
>>> rx.match("10.5")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='10.5'>

